# Javascript not working on IE 7 and IE 8 on Vista

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, windows-vista, internet-explorer-7

An Example of this can be seen here:
     http://nces.ed.gov/datalab/quickstats/default.aspx
Try clicking on one of the groups on the left and it should refresh the workspace with that group.

It works fine on all browsers in Windows 7 but fails in IE 7 and IE 8 on Vista.

I have this function:

```
     function SelectGroup(gid, glevel, gtext) {
         alert('not running on my environment only in vista');
    }
```

And this is what calls it:

```
      <a href="javascript:SelectGroup('3','3','Beginning college students')" style='text-decoration:none;'><span id='span_draggable_3' onmouseover="NavOver('3','3')" onmouseout="NavOut('3','3')" style='cursor:pointer;'>Beginning college students</span></a></div>
```

Comment: i am pretty sure that your OS doesn't affect how your browser executes JS?

Comment: yeah but we have tried it on multiple machines running ie9 - all vista machines fail for ie7 and ie8 and all windows 7 machines work fine.

Comment: go to the link above, agree to quickstats if you have too, then under groups click on beginning college students. In IE9 the group opens up, but not on vista in ie7 and ie8.

Comment: works in IE8 on XP.  Are you sure it's not some odd configuration setting of that particular Vista machine you're testing on?

Comment: yeah it was an ie9 then we used debug tools to check ie8 and ie 7 on two separate vista machines...i'm gonna try get a standalone one and test it in vista

Comment: -1 on the question because you don't explain what doesn't work or provide any context.  You're expecting the reader to go figure out what doesn't work by playing with the web page.  Providing the actual web page is a good thing, but you should distill the question down to describe what doesn't work and what you've done to look into the issue so far.

Comment: Your function SelectGroup as expressed above has a typo in it and probably won't run.  The quote mark after gered is out of place.  Plus it's unclear what the gered part of that line is doing anyway.

Comment: Using IE8/XP here so can't do a full test.  I wonder if it has anything to do with that drag-and-drop behavior you've got.  Maybe try to disable it and see if that fixes regular link clicking in IE Vista.

Answer (score 4):

Some general suggestions:

1. Try to look if you have error messages, what do you mean by *failed*?
2. Try first with FireFox, it has better development tools.
3. IE8 has decent enough debugging tools, why wouldn't you use this?
4. Use a library like Mootools and JQuery to abstract differences between the major browsers
5. What about the old `alert` way of debugging things, have you tried it?
6. Try to narrow the problem the best you can, from my experience, this snipet is too big

edit: By telling in comments alerts don't run, it means you have an actual JS error somewhere and not a logic bug. Click on the error signal, bottom left of browser (yellow triangle with ! I believe), what is the message?

Edit: My friend, you have two other events I missed, What is the code of the `onmouseover` event, this might trash your code.
**AND** you have a `</span>` in the wrong place (no matching opening tag) this can also cause issues.

Comment: did all these things already...alerts don't run...i guess no one has tried to actually go to the link in IE then?

Comment: no, you did not, code is still way too big. Did it work with FF? Also, give the code with the Alerts you used. Also, I do not see u using any library, even just for the sake of seeing if it helps, which can help figure out where the problem is. Seriously, I think you need to put more into it.

Comment: code is small now, but the guy above actually checked the link out, i beat you're not even running vista

Comment: and nope no js errors either, must be a vista/ie config thing (runs ffine everywhere else) and yes the above has been editted and still doesn't work

Comment: @chris I am on linux with no GUI/desktop and Lynx as browser, I am a software monk, "thu shall not use any GUI and shall see only green and black"

Comment: @chris, the syntax error in the current example is in the post only, or in the real code too? It should be only: alert('not running on my environment only in vista');` instead of 'alert('not running on my environment only in vista');gered');'